# Is there a way to change UILabel line spacing throughout the whole app like using UIAppearance or something like that

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, uiappearance

I am trying to set the line spacing of all used UILabel in my app. I have found a solution to set line spacing using NSMutableParagraphStyle and attributedText but I am trying to find another solution to do that in one place thought all the app. Is it possible?

Comment: You could add an extension on UILabel and add a function to have custom logic. Then invoke that function on any UILabel instance

Comment: I 'm trying tp find a way to set it in all label in on place as a configuration instead of doing it every time i use label

Answer (score 0):

or you can create custom UILabel class and set this class in storyboard and assign to UIlabel class.Than it automatically acquire the properties of custom class.

Comment: "you can create custom UILabel" you mean subclass UILabel

Comment: create class that inherit from uiLabel class

Comment: That’s called subclassing

Comment: good solution but I need to set it in one place like configuration to be done automatically even without using custom class. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can create exetesion and directly set the line spacing from storyboard.`

```
@IBInspectable var lineSpacing : CGFloat{
        set{
            if let text = self.text{
                let attribText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = newValue //direct set Default value
                attribText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attribText.length))
                self.attributedText = attribText
            }
        }

        get{
            return 2
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: not working and justing by making the extention all my label's text became emty and I can't Know the reason behind that